# How to update the SecurityContextHolder username for the update for current user

Tags: java, spring-security

In my application when the current logged in user's usernam is changed i want to update the UserDetails principal for the current user. How can I do that? I'm getting the current username by following method :

```
 public UserDetails getSystemUser(){
    try {
        UserDetails principal  = (UserDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        return  principal;
    }catch (ClassCastException e){
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess that there is not a method to set username. So you will probably have to create a new context and a new authentication object and add it to that context and that context add it to the SecurityContextHolder. I can post an answer to how exactly do that if necessary.

Comment: @Merv yeah please post it, that would be pretty helpful

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there is no setusername method for this.

Keep in mind this solution is untested it might or not work.

So first clearcontext. Then create a new empty context and set the newly created authentication object with the updated username and all OTHER INFO needed.

- @ 'newusername' you should set your new updated username string or
  your customuserdetails object with your new updated username and all other
  info.

> ```
> Authentication oldAuthenticationObject = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
>
> SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
> SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
> UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication =
>                 new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
>                 NEWUSERNAME,
>                 null,
>                 oldAuthenticationObject.getAuthorities());
> context.setAuthentication(authentication);
> SecurityContextHolder.setContext(context);
> ```

Comment: But when i add this code snippet and call it as a method i get a null pointer exception when i'm trying to get the current username.